# Pivot a table on two value columns

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to pivot a table on two columns (we did some normalization on our table but need to create a view for backwards compatibility). My new data structure is this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Products (
  product VARCHAR(30),
  market_year INT,
  value INT,
  description varchar(20));

INSERT INTO #Products VALUES('Corn', 2003, 100, 'bad');
INSERT INTO #Products VALUES('Beer', 2003, 200, 'not so bad');
INSERT INTO #Products VALUES('Beef', 2003, 150, 'good');

INSERT INTO #Products VALUES('Corn', 2004, 10, 'doo');
INSERT INTO #Products VALUES('Beer', 2004, 20, 'foo');
INSERT INTO #Products VALUES('Beef', 2004, 10, 'bar');
```

which looks Like:

```
SELECT * FROM #Products p;

product market_year value   description
Corn        2003    100     bad
Beer        2003    200     not so bad
Beef        2003    150     good
Corn        2004    10      doo
Beer        2004    20      foo
Beef        2004    10      bar
```

The result I need should look like the following:

```
market_year |corn_value |corn_description | beer_value | beer_description |beef_value | beef_description
2003        | 100       |bad              | 150        | NOT so bad       |150        | good
2003        | 10        |doo              | 15         | foo              |15         | bar
```

I know I could do this with two separate statements with one pivot each on market_year and join them by market_year but that would require this table to be read twice. Is there a more elegant way to solve this issue?
(my table has approximately 7 million records split by 70 columns that need to be reverted to 140 columns)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use dynamic pivot

declare two var `@CONTENT` to represnt pivot sql query `CASE WHEN` with `MAX`
then use `@sql` to connecte your query sql and use `execute` execute this sql dynamically.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX),@CONTENT VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @CONTENT = STUFF((
    SELECT ', '+'MAX(CASE WHEN product = '''+ product + ''' THEN [VALUE] END) AS '''+product+'_value'',
        MAX(CASE WHEN product = '''+ product + ''' THEN [description] END) AS '''+product+'_value'''
    FROM #Products 
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,2,'')

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT market_year,' + @CONTENT + ' FROM #Products GROUP BY market_year';
execute(@SQL)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=156e8fb3d980578ff1b7ab2cd77e08ab)

Comment: Thank you. Very short SQL but for me this would create 140 case when statements which I think take a lot of computation time.

Answer (score 0):

select *
from 
(
  select  market_year,product, value
  from #products p
) src
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for product in (Beer, Com, Beef)
) piv;

try this it will help you to get some idea

Comment: That's part of the solution I already have, I am looking for a way to avoid two of the above suggested SELECTs

Comment: what problem you have with D-Shih solution ??

Comment: it is to slow. For my real dataset I have 70 different products, resulting in 140 Case WHEN Statements